# Get Facebook app to use full screen in Android 2.3?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, facebook

Is it possible to make the Facebook app in Android 2.3 use the full screen? I remember being able to do this on a different device with Android 1.6 but I can't find a way to do it with Android 2.3.

Comment: I think its app dependent rather than OS version dependent.

Comment: Are you talking about the official facebook app? Maybe things have changed

Comment: I am talking about the official app, yes.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is certainly not eligible for the bounty, but I'm afraid the answer is: *it's not possible*.

Even though I can't share resources that *do* tell us that it's not possible, I *can* share resources you'd expect to have the answer, but don't:

- This [Google-fu](http://www.google.com/search?q=Hide+top+bar+in+Facebook+app+for+Android+) leads mostly to development threads
- Again, [with "-developer"](http://www.google.com/search?q=Hide+top+bar+in+Facebook+app+for+Android+-developer) added things don't improve much
- The [help center on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/search/?q=Android) is utterly useless as well, even with [more specific queries](https://www.facebook.com/help/search/?q=Android+hide+top+bar)
- The settings for Version 1.8.4 of the Facebook app do not contain any remotely close option (there aren't too many settings, anyway).

Perhaps someone else can refute this answer?

Comment: You're almost right ;) There's a way that works for some apps, but I'll have to verify if it works with Facebook.